# How to code the camera to be opened within an app I made?

Tags: java, android, camera, viewer

I am trying to develop an app that uses the camera in it, as far as my app being opened and it has a viewer of the camera below it. I have googled all over. By the way this is an Android app, in which I am using java, and eclipse to write it in. Help me please

Answer (score 2):

I just Googled (*camera app android code*) and found http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html, is this what you're after?

Comment: Thanks Chris, Exacttly what I was looking for!